# How to get Id of a post as soon as i save them in database?

Tags: laravel

As soon as i save post in `database` i need to redirect to another page for the image upload of same post.
    For that i need to have the id of post that is being recently posted.
    Because in `database` table i have
    id `post_id` image

So, this is the code where post gets save in the database and redirects it to the another page for the image upload.

```
if(PostAd::create($data))
{
   return redirect()->route('postimageupload');
}
```

Comment: I want you to show me the methods I have saved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the newly created post in a variable. And then redirect to the route with the id of the newly created post. Assuming your route is like

```
Route::get('image/add/{id}', 'YourController@addimage')->name('postimageupload');
```

And in Controller

```
$post =  PostAd::create($data);
return redirect()->route('postimageupload',$post->id);
```